# Trying to get a written Intraclass Correlation Coefficient function to work, R

Tags: r, function

I am working with a function that someone else wrote. It is suppose to calculate the intraclass correlation coefficient (ICC). However, it is throwing an error. And I cannot figure out what is causing the error.

Here is my data

```
df<-structure(list(RegNum = c(1001, 101003, 104004, 104013, 105001, 
1006, 104009, 101044, 102001, 104005, 1011, 104001, 101036, 101027, 
104007, 1016, 105004, 104012, 102004, 104008, 1021, 101038, 105002, 
101041, 104003, 1026, 104014, 105005, 1029), beta_Alanine = c(2086L, 
2041L, 1924L, 951L, 884L, 1076L, 524L, 3341L, 838L, 3063L, 2637L, 
1346L, 1306L, 2352L, 4593L, 3133L, 2240L, 2620L, 1644L, 5649L, 
1630L, 1489L, 5492L, 1247L, 6004L, 2925L, 2526L, 2233L, 1508L
)), row.names = 2:30, class = "data.frame")
```

Here is the function:

```r
icc9 <- function(y,subject,fixed=NULL,dat,method="ML"){
  
    # Quick install from github
    p <-   rownames(installed.packages())
    if ("devtools" %in% p == "FALSE") install.packages("devtools")
    if ("bootmlm" %in% p == "FALSE") devtools::install_github("marklhc/bootmlm")
  
    data <- dat
  
    # quick function to format my estimates/confidence intervals
    formatEstimate <- function(est, lcl, ucl){
    a <- format(round(est,2),nsmall=2)
    b <- format(round(lcl,2),nsmall=2)
    c <- format(round(ucl,2),nsmall=2)
    return(paste0(a, " (",b,",",c,")"))
    }
  
    # drop any missings from the dataset
    dat <- dat[!is.na(dat[[subject]]),]
    dat <- dat[!is.na(dat[[y]]),]
  
    # Define my input variables
    SUBJECT <- data[[subject]]
    Y <- data[[y]]
    if (is.null(fixed)) {FIXED <- NULL} else {FIXED <- as.matrix(data[,fixed])}
  
    # Frequency stuff first
    tabx.f <- data.frame(table(SUBJECT))
    tabx.p <- data.frame(prop.table(table(SUBJECT)))
    tabx <- data.frame(subjid=tabx.f$SUBJECT, COUNT=tabx.f$Freq, 
    PERCENT=tabx.p$Freq*100,
                     stringsAsFactors=F)
    rm(tabx.f,tabx.p)
  
  
    # tab3 lists the number of unique subjects, number of observations, and average 
    obs per subject
    tab3 <- data.frame(numw2=nrow(tabx),
                     obsw2=sum(tabx$COUNT,na.rm=T))
    tab3$avgrep <- tab3$obsw2/tab3$numw2
    rm(tabx)
  
    # Step 1 - run the model
    # Subject ID is always a random effects
    # Y is the response
    # FIXED is optional
    # Method - inputs are "ML" or "REML", default is "ML"
  
    # Sets modelmethod to logical
    # the lmer() function has an option "REML=T/F"
    # This little bit of code will just fill in that option
    if (method == "ML") modelmethod <- F
    if (method != "ML") modelmethod <- T
  
    if (!is.null(FIXED)) {
    f <- formula(paste0("Y ~ ",paste(c("(1|SUBJECT)","FIXED"),collapse="+")))
    } else {
    f <- formula("Y ~ (1|SUBJECT)")
    }
    fit <- lme4::lmer(f, REML=modelmethod)  # model object
    z <- summary(fit)       # summary object
  
    # Extract the asymptotic covariance matrix
    asycov <- data.frame(bootmlm::vcov_vc(fit,F))
    names(asycov) <- c("CovP1","CovP2")  # Renaming to match the SAS program
    row.names(asycov) <- c("Intercept","Residual")
  
    # Pull out the covariance parameters
    estimates <- data.frame(z$varcor)
    estimates <- estimates[,c("grp","vcov","sdcor")]
    names(estimates) <- c("Parm","Estimate","SD")
  
    # Pull out the fixed effects estimates
    fixed_effects <- data.frame(z$coefficients)[1,]
    names(fixed_effects) <- c("Estimate","SE","T")
  
    # Everything I need is in the asycov, random-estimates and fixed-estimates 
    matrices
    subject_estimate <- estimates$Estimate[estimates$Parm=="SUBJECT"]
    residual_estimate <- estimates$Estimate[estimates$Parm=="Residual"]
    residual_covp2 <- asycov["Residual","CovP2"]
    intercept_covp1 <- asycov["Intercept","CovP1"]
    intercept_covp2 <- asycov["Intercept","CovP2"]
    fixed_estimate <- fixed_effects$Estimate
    variance_fixed <- fixed_effects$SE^2
  
  
    # ICC and confidence intervals
    ICC_Variance <- (subject_estimate^2 * residual_covp2+residual_estimate^2 * 
    intercept_covp1- 
    2*subject_estimate*residual_estimate*intercept_covp2)/subject_estimate^4
    ICC <- estimates$Estimate[estimates$Parm=="SUBJECT"] / sum(estimates$Estimate)
    logICC <- log(ICC / (1-ICC))
    SE_ICC <- sqrt(((ICC^2) * ICC_Variance) / ((1-ICC)^2))
    logLL <- logICC - 1.96*SE_ICC
    logUL <- logICC + 1.96*SE_ICC
    ICCLL <- exp(logLL) / (1+exp(logLL))
    ICCUL <- exp(logUL) / (1+exp(logUL))
    finalICC <- formatEstimate(ICC, ICCLL, ICCUL)
    rm(ICC_Variance,logICC,ICC,SE_ICC,logLL,logUL,ICCLL,ICCUL)
  
  
  
    # Overall CV
    Variance_CV <- residual_covp2 / (4*fixed_estimate^2 * residual_estimate) +
    (residual_estimate / fixed_estimate^4) * variance_fixed
  
    CV <- sqrt(residual_estimate) / z$coefficients["(Intercept)","Estimate"]
    logCV <- log(CV)
    varCV <- (1/CV^2) * Variance_CV
    logLL <- logCV - 1.96*sqrt(varCV)
    logUL <- logCV + 1.96*sqrt(varCV)
    CVLL <- exp(logLL)
    CVUL <- exp(logUL)
    finalCV <- formatEstimate(CV, CVLL, CVUL)
  
    # Create a final data frame with:
    # n-unique subject
    # n-observations
    # avg-N per subject
    final <- data.frame(Response=y,tab3,ICC=finalICC,CV=finalCV,stringsAsFactors=F)
    names(final) <- 
    c("Response_Variable","N_subjects","N_Observations","Average_Measurements",
    "ICC","CV")
    return(final)
    }
```

Here is where I tried to use the function:

```
icc9(y=df$beta_Alanine,subject = "RegNum", dat=df)
```

Here is the error it returns:

```
Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : no such index at level 1
```

I am not sure what is causing the error.

Comment: Try calling with `icc9(y="beta_Alanine", subject = "RegNum", dat=df)` It looks like the function wants the name of the column as the `y` value, not the values themselves.

Comment: I just tried that. It produced a new error: Error: number of levels of each grouping factor must be < number of observations (problems: SUBJECT)

Comment: Do you only have one value per subject? What are you trying to calculate the correlation for in that case? The function seems to assume you have multiple observations per subject.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to fix the issue based on your last comment